# Comparación input con integer

Tags: javascript

Pregunta básica de newbie, será una tontería, pero estoy dándole vueltas y no veo el problema...

Tengo un input en mi HTML y quiero comparar el valor introducido con la longitud de un array.

La forma en que obtengo el valor del input es así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien, este bucle FOR funciona correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando llega al límite se sale con el Break y hace lo que tiene que hacer. (si pongo en el input 5 sale cuando en el array hay 5 entradas, si pongo 10 a la décima, etc... lo he probado y va bien)

Pero más abajo tengo otro IF en el que simplemente comparo si la longitud del array es menor al dato introducido en el input y en este IF no entra nunca...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el debugger veo que están bien los dos valores como enteros, debería hacer bien la comparación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando el método parseInt para convertir el string introducido en un entero y comparar así con el array.lenght pero no entra nunca en este segundo IF...

He probado el parseInt con base 10 como está en la imagen y sin pasarle nada en la base, pero nada, no funciona.

¿Qué me falta?

Comment: Saludos, primeramente el código debe ir como texto por favor, y segundo podrías hacer un `console.log(preguntas.length, max, preguntas.length < max);` justo antes del *if* donde ves el problema, para ver que te muestra. ;)

Comment: Puedes saltarte el parseInt con document.getElementById('tuelemento').valueAsNumber, ten en cuenta que escribiste mal .length

Answer (score 1):

Iba a dejar esto sin comentario alguno, pero el sistema de respuesta me obliga a escribir al menos 30 caracteres en la misma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No me puedo creer que sea esa tontería ! Y no te da el compilador ningún error por inventarte un campo??? Bueno, ya iré aprendiendo...